# Exclude completed deadlines from orgmode's ical export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, ical

I have enabled the inclusion of deadlines in the ical export of orgmode by setting the preference `org-icalendar-use-deadline '(todo-due event-if-todo)`. How can I exclude an orgmode heading from exporting when it is marked as done? At the moment my calendar is cluttered with completed tasks.